# In PowerShell v3 why does storing the result of of an expression result in a different object?

Tags: powershell

This question is purely to advance my understanding of PowerShell.

I'm trying to understand what is actually happening under the covers, when interacting with a pipe using the measure command, compared to when I store the  results of the pipe in a variable and use measure on it.  I get different objects/values.

If I first do:

```
echo '[1,2,3,4,5]' | ConvertFrom-Json | measure
```

I get:

```
Count    : 1
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :
```

However, if I then capture the result in a variable and do:

```
$obj = echo '[1,2,3,4,5]' | ConvertFrom-Json
$obj | measure
```

I get:

```
Count    : 5
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :
```

I can see the type of the variable `$obj` is `System.Array`.

```
PS> $obj.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

I don't know to see the type, when in the pipe being passed to the `measure` command (think it is type object).

Comment: To replicate, you need to enclose your expression in parentheses before piping to `Measure` -> `(echo '[1,2,3,4,5]' | convertfrom-json) | measure`.

Comment: Thanks, but what is adding the parentheses doing under the covers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior should become clearer if you look at the actual output of the conversion by replacing `Measure-Object` with `Get-Member`:

```
PS C:\> echo '[1,2,3,4,5]' | ConvertFrom-Json | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Object[]

Name           MemberType            Definition
----           ----------            ----------
Count          AliasProperty         Count = Length
...
PS C:\> $obj = echo '[1,2,3,4,5]' | ConvertFrom-Json
PS C:\> $obj | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Int32

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
CompareTo   Method     int CompareTo(System.Object value), int Compa...
...
```

Basically, what's happening is that `ConvertTo-Json` produces an array object that is consumed by the next cmdlet as-is. Hence `Measure-Object` counts only one item (the array).

By capturing the object in a variable before passing it to the next cmdlet the array gets unrolled, so that `Measure-Object` sees (and counts) the *elements* of the array.

You can get the same result you get from capturing the conversion output in a variable by putting the conversion in a grouping expression:

```
PS C:\> $obj = echo '[1,2,3,4,5]' | ConvertFrom-Json
PS C:\> $obj | Measure-Object

Count    : 5
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :

PS C:\> (echo '[1,2,3,4,5]' | ConvertFrom-Json) | Measure-Object

Count    : 5
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```